# How to add nail head pins in eagle

Tags: eaglecad, pins

I am new to cad drawings and eagle cad. My professor wants me to build a pcb which has these nail head pins: https://www.mill-max.com/products/pin/5063/5063-0-00-01-00-00-33-0

I am not able to the part that lets me add individual pins (not pin headers). If there is no such part, how do I create that part and how will the pcb printing guy understand the part (since this part wont be in his set of libraries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the 1 pin pin header you have to make your own library (if you changed your mind and you are willing to use them go to the pinhead library).

The following link is a tutorial on how to make your own library in eagle.

[click here for the tutorial](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/110)

The 'pcb printing guy' (the manufacturer) won't need your library because you will most likely send him the gerber files. Also if you send your whole project (all your eagle project files) he will also have the component in there, even if he doesn't have the library. He just can't edit the library or use that library on other projects.